# fork-exec with ease of use of system()

Tags: c

Is there any easy way to implement a `fork()` and `execve()` in a single function call? Something like `system()` but without all the shell stuff behind the scenes.

Comment: Is it more than 10 lines of straightforward code?  I'm not exactly sure  what you're looking for here--C is not a language known for including a lot of batteries!

Comment: Is performance what you are worrying about?

Comment: Use a library. For instance glib has a very nice group of [process spawning functions](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Spawning-Processes.html) that make it quite easy.

Comment: `g_spawn_sync` is indeed close enough to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
pid_t 
fork_and_execve(const char *path, char *const argv[], char *const envp[])
{
    pid_t child_pid;
    child_pid = fork();
    if (0 == child_pid) {
        execve(path, argv, envp);
    } else {
        return child_pid;
    }
}
```

note that this code doesn't handle if the `execve()` call fails

Comment: I know how to write the fork-execve boilerplate code. I want to avoid it using a single standard call.

Comment: The answer is that there isn't one. Process spawning in unix is done by fork-execve, you might find a library that implements the above boilerplate, but there is no system-call that does so.

Answer (score 2):

Sure:

```
pid_t start(char *cmd, char **argv, char **envp) {
    pid_t child = fork();
    if(child == 0) {
        execve(cmd, argv, envp);
        _exit(1);
    }
    return child;
}

int invoke(char *cmd, char **argv, char **envp) {
    int status;
    waitpid(start(cmd, argv, envp), &status);
    return status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For POSIX systems there exists [`posix_spawn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn.html):

> The  **posix_spawn()**  and  **posix_spawnp()**  functions shall create a new process (child process) from the specified process image. The new process image shall be constructed from a regular executable file called the new process
>          image file.